# How to show change greetings title based on gender_id with php?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write on email template Mr. or Mrs. based on gender id how ever I just get Good Morning Adams(Surname)

```
<span class="ed_titel" style="font-family:Arial;color:#555555;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:20px;text-align:left;">
<b>Good Morning, 
<?php 
  if ($contact.gender_id == 1){echo "Mr. "} 
  elseif($contact.gender_id == 2){echo "Mrs. "} ?> 
  {contact.last_name}!</b>
</span>
```

Comment: make an `else`, I think it doesn't match with any of `if`

Comment: print_r($contact.gender_id); and see what you get,  or try if ($contact["gender_id"]==1)

Comment: What about other genders?

Comment: do `var_dump($contact);` before `if` condition and show us the output of it. Add it in your question

Comment: yes @AlivetoDie is correct please var_dump($contact); and show us the output

Comment: Dot `.` is a concatenation character in PHP

Comment: @DainisAbols What other genders?

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt https://news.vice.com/article/trans-people-told-to-leave-gender-blank-on-canadas-census

Comment: <b>Good Morning,
   {contact.gender_id}
    {contact.last_name}!</b>

If i write like this then I get

Good Morning 1 "My Surname"

Answer (score 1):

Getting element from Object in php by `->` not by `.` dot

Use

```
$contact->gender_id // if its array $contact["gender_id"]
```

Instead of

```
$contact.gender_id
```

Comment: Or `$contact['gender_id']`, if it's an array. You cant really tell that from the small piece he provided.

Comment: it didnt work with ->

 <b>Good Morning, {contact.gender_id} {contact.last_name}!</b> If i write like this then I get Good Morning 1 "My Surname"

Answer (score 1):

try using 
1 (if $contact is an object)

```
$contact->gender_id
```

or 2 (if $contact is an array)

```
$contact["gender_id"]
```

in the if condition

Answer (score 0):

Your $contact.gender_id is obviously not what you expect it to be (1 or 2), so if you replace else if with just else, you will surely get Mrs. printed.

Comment: Well, no. He just uses concatenating instead of calling the property of the object/element of the array.

Comment: So what is wrong with the answer? That concated string is not what he expects it to be :)

Comment: It is wrong, since you are implying that `if you replace else if with just else, you will surely get Mrs. printed`. This is true, but in every case, since the if will never be correct until he fixes his broken code.

Comment: So you are telling me that `if(false)` `else print "else"` will not print else. I did not give exact solution, I just wanted him to point him in right direction, regardless of other mistakes he made. I agree that my answer could be comprehended in many ways....

Comment: I did not say that. What I said is, that if you just replace the elseif with else, you will get if (false) always

Comment: I must use elseif because there are some users in database who havent given the gender.

Comment: it didnt work with ->

 <b>Good Morning, {contact.gender_id} {contact.last_name}!</b> If i write like this then I get Good Morning 1 "My Surname"

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="ed_titel" style="font-family:Arial;color:#555555;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;line-height:20px;text-align:left;">
<b>Good Morning,
<span id="gender"><?php ((1 === $contact->gender_id) ? 'Mr. ' : 'Mrs. '); ?></span>
  {contact->last_name}!</b>
</span>
```

See if this works. I'm assuming that you aren't directly sending this code over to someone's mailing box....

Comment: What about `<span id="gender"><?=((1 === $contact->gender_id) ? 'Mr. ' : 'Mrs. '); ?></span>`. Much shorter and also only need for one span tag :)

Comment: It didnt work.And I must use elseif because there are some users in database who havent given the gender.

Comment: it didnt work with ->

 <b>Good Morning, {contact.gender_id} {contact.last_name}!</b> If i write like this then I get Good Morning 1 "My Surname"

Comment: what data structure is it? $contacts? is it an array or an object...?? print_r($contacts)

Comment: I get no result for print_r($contacts)
   When I change the code like this; Good Morning <?php
    
    print_r($contacts)
   ?>
   {contact.gender_id}
    {contact.last_name}!</b>

I still get Good Morning 1 "My Surname"